# remove/hide legend chart excel

Tags: c#, charts, excel-2007, legend

hi i have this following code

```
 private static void exportChart()
    {
        Excel.Range chartRange;
        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)oWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 150);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("E5", "F13");
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

        Excel.Range chartPlacementRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("F11", "F11");
        myChart.Left = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Top);
        myChart.Top = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Left);
    }
```

i try to remove/hide legend in chart, i already try code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994786/how-do-i-remove-an-excel-chart-legend-entry-with-c) link

```
chart.Legend.LegendEnteries(chart.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete();
```

so in my case it would be like this

```
chartPage.Legend.LegendEntries(chartPage.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete();
```

but unfortunatelly this is as far as i can..... (after type LegendEntries twice it's not available .count or .delete)

```
chartPage.Legend.LegendEntries(chartPage.Legend.LegendEntries());
```

how to do it correctly?

Comment: update i already found it...
it's actually really simple with just 'chartPage.Legend.Clear();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured it out in your comment, but I think it's better to consider this as a answer. So there is goes:

```
chartPage.Legend.Clear();
```