How to add text box in graph area to show percentage value of each legend in stacked bar chart OfficeOpenXML or EPPlus C#?
I have stacked bar chart, in that I want to show percentage for each label(80% for PDD1 label). 80 is number we can show between first 2 bars(here 3 diff label have 2 bars for each).
Note: 80% value is not specific to first bar, it there between 2 bars.

So I added percentage records but can't hide from chart and show at top mid of each label area.
I tried some articles solution( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036445/11010986 ) but i can't see the LoadEntries option in OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart
chart1.Legend.LoadEntries(chart1.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete()


I saw Entries option but it's readonly.
Edit 1:
Data for Chart:

C# Code block:
dynamic DataList5 = new
{
    label = new List<string>() { "PDD1", "PDD2", "PDD3" },
    modeler = new { Category1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1 }, Category2 = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0 } },
    tester = new { Category1 = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2 }, Category2 = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2 } },
    percentage = new List<int>() { 150, 200, 10 }
};


if (DataList5.label.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DataList5.label.Count * 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = DataList5.label[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = "Category 1";
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = DataList5.modeler.Category1[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = DataList5.tester.Category1[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = DataList5.percentage[j];
        }
        else
        {
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = "Category 2";
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = DataList5.modeler.Category2[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = DataList5.tester.Category2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    ws2.Cells[2, 2].Value = "No Data Found";
}
var chart1 = ws1.Drawings.AddChart("chart1", eChartType.ColumnStacked);
chart1.SetPosition(1, 0, 0, 0);
chart1.SetSize(1800, 400);
chart1.Style = eChartStyle.Style12;

if (DataList5.label.Count > 0)
{
    var series1 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["D2:D" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);
    var series2 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["E2:E" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);
//percentage series
    //var series3 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["F2:F" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);


    series1.Fill.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 112, 192);
    series2.Fill.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 239, 125, 49);

//Show percentage for each PDD1 label
    ////chart1.Legend.LoadEntries(chart1.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete();

    series1.Header = "Modeler";
    series2.Header = "Tester";
    //series3.Header = "Percentage";

}
else
{
    var series1 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList1.label.Count + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList1.label.Count + 1)]);
}

chart1.Title.Text = "Stacked bar chart example";

Result is:

Here showing percentage is problem for me.
even PDD1 should come between first 2 bars but that's not major concern here.
Edit 2: My question here is can we add text box that should show percentage value of each label as following:

Anyone has idea about solution in C# EPPlus or OfficeOpenXML?

Excel has that as one of the selectable chart options iirc.

means? not getting you.

@rock the API of either the Open XML SDK or higher level libraries like EPPlus usually match the Excel features or the VBA API. What you posted are data labels for specific series, formatted a certain way. Try looking for the chart's series, labels etc and try to set the equivalent properties

In the EPPlus chart examples I see that a Series object has a DataLabel property.

Check the duplicate. It creates a bar chart with a series and data labels that appear as a percentage, with leader lines. You could change the label position to eLabelPosition.Top to display the label at the top

@PanagiotisKanavos - i tried with DataLabel and eLablePosition.Top as these are related label (in my example PDD1), and not working as solution to my issue, thanks for your suggestions.

What does that mean? If you want to show data labels you have to use the DataLabel class and its properties. What did you expect and what did you get? The question's code doesn't set the labels of either series1 or series2. What did you do to get the result in the question? You need to replicate those settings in code. PDD1 is just a cell value, not a series

EPPlus is close enough to the Excel object model that you could record a VBA macro while creating the cart you want and use the same properties in your code.

@PanagiotisKanavos, can you please look into my edited code as binding all code block, data i have and result i got. Thanks

So, just using a standard chart available in Excel with the data labels added:


The question didn't ask how to show labels in Excel. It asked how to generate them programmatically, either with the low level OpenXML SDK or higher level libraries like EPPlus

understood, but looking solution from C# EPPlus not in excel. thanks.

@PanagiotisKanavos so if you set up the chart completed with dummy data as a template, then all you need to do is paste in fresh data. Seems to be like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut by using code for this.

@rock you tagged Excel so expect a solution using it. Especially when you state "any solutions" without limiting them to particular code.

@SolarMike, sorry i corrected my statment, Thanks.

@solarmike There's nothing wrong with the Excel tag, this is an Excel question. SO is a programming Q&A site and there are several questions about programmatic Excel generation already, using the Office SDK, Epplus or one of the many other related libraries. Even if you create template files (which are supported by the various libraries) you still need a way to change the data

@PanagiotisKanavos pasting data is easy, so many answers showing that on here already, which you can find with a bit of research.

And many of these I wrote myself. Although the duplicate question answers the problem exactly (apart from some positioning and formatting). This answer is missing the point - this has to be done programmatically by an application or web app, not by hand.

@PanagiotisKanavos that was not stated when I answered the original question, which you can easily check.
