How to add image/text in graph area to show percentage value of each legend in stacked bar chart OfficeOpenXML or EPPlus C#?
I have stacked bar chart, in that I want to show percentage for each label(80% for PDD1 label). 80 is number we can show between first 2 bars(here 3 diff label have 2 bars for each).
Note: 80% value is not specific to first bar, it there between 2 bars.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
So I added percentage records but can't hide from chart and show at top mid of each label area.
I tried some articles solution( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036445/11010986 ) but i can't see the LoadEntries option in OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart
chart1.Legend.LoadEntries(chart1.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete()
I saw Entries option but it's readonly.
Edit 1: Data for Chart: [![enter image description here][2]][2]
C# Code block:

dynamic DataList5 = new
{
    label = new List<string>() { "PDD1", "PDD2", "PDD3" },
    modeler = new { Category1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1 }, Category2 = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0 } },
    tester = new { Category1 = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2 }, Category2 = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 2 } },
    percentage = new List<int>() { 150, 200, 10 }
};


if (DataList5.label.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DataList5.label.Count * 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = DataList5.label[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = "Category 1";
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = DataList5.modeler.Category1[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = DataList5.tester.Category1[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = DataList5.percentage[j];
        }
        else
        {
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = "Category 2";
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = DataList5.modeler.Category2[j];
            ws2.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = DataList5.tester.Category2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    ws2.Cells[2, 2].Value = "No Data Found";
}
var chart1 = ws1.Drawings.AddChart("chart1", eChartType.ColumnStacked);
chart1.SetPosition(1, 0, 0, 0);
chart1.SetSize(1800, 400);
chart1.Style = eChartStyle.Style12;

if (DataList5.label.Count > 0)
{
    var series1 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["D2:D" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);
    var series2 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["E2:E" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);
//percentage series
    //var series3 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["F2:F" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList5.label.Count * 2 + 1)]);


    series1.Fill.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 112, 192);
    series2.Fill.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 239, 125, 49);

//Show percentage for each PDD1 label
    ////chart1.Legend.LoadEntries(chart1.Legend.LegendEntries().Count).Delete();

    series1.Header = "Modeler";
    series2.Header = "Tester";
    //series3.Header = "Percentage";

}
else
{
    var series1 = chart1.Series.Add(ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList1.label.Count + 1)], ws2.Cells["B2:C" + (DataList1.label.Count + 1)]);
}```

chart1.Title.Text = "Stacked bar chart example";
Result is: [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Here showing percentage is problem for me.

even PDD1 should come between first 2 bars but that's not major concern here.

Edit 2: My question here is can we add text box that should show percentage value of each label as following:

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Anyone has idea about solution in C# EPPlus or OfficeOpenXML?


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/wijHekfY.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/KPSPOf9G.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBG5RMAf.png
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/VgbspPth.png


This question is similar to: How to add text box in graph area to show percentage value of each legend in stacked bar chart OfficeOpenXML or EPPlus C#?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Pang - I created this because of same question marked as duplicate which is not actually duplicate.

I have created a image dynamically for each chart using Image and Stream objects and placed image byte array at exact position of the excel by using Drawings.AddPicture by calculating position as per my logic(split by value = chart size/legends count).
Note: Answering this as I don't want to get closed my question by wrongly.
Code for Draw image for given text:
{

    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    System.Drawing.Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();
    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    return xByte;

}


and code for inserting above methods byte[] into excel:
int PixelTop = 60;
int PixelLeft = 870;
int diff = 0;
if (count > 1)
{
    diff = 1800 / (count + 1);
    diff = diff / 2;
    PixelLeft = diff + (diff / 2);
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    byte[] bytes = DrawText(DataList5.percentage[i] + "%", font, Color.Black, Color.White);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    ExcelPicture pic = ws1.Drawings.AddPicture(DataList5.label[i] + i, stream);
    pic.SetPosition(PixelTop, PixelLeft);
    //ws1.Protection.IsProtected = false;
    //ws1.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = false;
    PixelLeft += (diff * 2);
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
